# What does the fields "MountLabel" and "ProcessLabel" mean in docker inspect

Tags: docker

When executing the command `docker inspect <container id>`, we get the output include the many fields. But I can't find out the meaning of `MountLabel` and `ProcessLabel`.

I get an annotation from the [source code](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/container/container.go#L83-L85) :

```
// MountLabel contains the options for the 'mount' command
```

and some example from [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/managing_containers/index):

```sh
# buildah inspect myecho-working-container | less
{
    "type": "buildah 0.0.1",
    "image": "docker.io/library/myecho:latest",
    "image-id": "e2b190ac8a37737ec03cfa4c9bfd989845b9bec3aa81ff48d8350d7418d748f6",
    "config": "eyJjcmV...
    "container-name": "myecho-working-container",
    "container-id": "70f22e886310bba26bb57ca7afa39fd19af2791c4c66067cb6206b7c3ebdcd20",
    "process-label": "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c225,c716",
    "mount-label": "system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c225,c716",
    "ociv1": {
        "created": "2017-10-12T15:15:00.207103Z",
        "author": "Red Hat, Inc.",
        "architecture": "amd64",
```

and the definition of the Container type which has those two fields from [fsouza/go-dockerclient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Container)

But I still can't figure out the meaning of those two fields, MountLabel and ProcessLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mount-label` is `SELinux label of mount (string)`.

`process-label` is `SELinux label of process (string)`.

ref:

- https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/podman-docker/docker-container-inspect.1.en
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#security-configuration

---

According to [ref](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/podman-docker/docker-container-inspect.1.en#OPTIONS), other fields of docker inspect have the following meanings:

Format the output using the given Go template. The keys of the returned JSON can be used as the values for the --format flag (see examples below).

Valid placeholders for the Go template are listed below:

| Placeholder | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Placeholder | Description |
| .AppArmorProfile | AppArmor profile (string) |
| .Args | Command-line arguments (array of strings) |
| .BoundingCaps | Bounding capability set (array of strings) |
| .Config ... | Structure with config info |
| .ConmonPidFile | Path to file containing conmon pid (string) |
| .Created | Container creation time (string, ISO3601) |
| .Dependencies | Dependencies (array of strings) |
| .Driver | Storage driver (string) |
| .EffectiveCaps | Effective capability set (array of strings) |
| .ExecIDs | ExecIDs (array)IDs (array of strings) |
| .GraphDriver ... | Further details of graph driver (struct) |
| .HostConfig ... | Host config details (struct) |
| .HostnamePath | Path to file containing hostname (string) |
| .HostsPath | Path to container /etc/hosts file (string) |
| .ID | Container ID (full 64-char hash) |
| .Image | Container image ID (64-char hash) |
| .ImageName | Container image name (string) |
| .IsInfra | Is this an infra container? (string: true/false) |
| .IsService | Is this a service container? (string: true/false) |
| .MountLabel | SELinux label of mount (string) |
| .Mounts | Mounts (array of strings) |
| .Name | Container name (string) |
| .Namespace | Container namespace (string) |
| .NetworkSettings ... | Network settings (struct) |
| .OCIConfigPath | Path to OCI config file (string) |
| .OCIRuntime | OCI runtime name (string) |
| .Path | Path to container command (string) |
| .PidFile | Path to file containing container PID (string) |
| .Pod | Parent pod (string) |
| .ProcessLabel | SELinux label of process (string) |
| .ResolvConfPath | Path to container's resolv.conf file (string) |
| .RestartCount | Number of times container has been restarted (int) |
| .Rootfs | Container rootfs (string) |
| .SizeRootFs | Size of rootfs, in bytes |
| .SizeRw | Size of upper (R/W) container layer, in bytes |
| .State ... | Container state info (struct) |
| .StaticDir | Path to container metadata dir (string) |